# Does a vector (container) need to use an "allocator"?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, vector, containers

I was looking into how custom containers are created, such as eastl's container and several other models and I see that they all use an "allocator", much like `std::vector` does with `std::allocator`. Which got me thinking, why do new implementations of a vector container use an allocator when they typically have an underlying memory management override for `new` and `delete`?

Comment: I think your assumptions are wrong. I can't make any sense of the last bit starting with "why", and I think it's fictional.

Comment: If you are looking at what allocators are and what role they play, read Als's answer below.
If you are looking at the code and see allocator objects being used despite the default allocators being reused, it's because the STL (being a _template_ library) has assumptions (e.g. each container defines classes called iterator and const_iterator and allocator, and each of these child classes have certain properties). Associating them (typically through typedefs and override functions) are done for the sake of completeness

Comment: (on above comment) I can't figure out a way to enter a line separator in a comment. Please delete this comment if it's the way it is, and please help me if there is a way I missed

Comment: My apologizes, I fixed the grammar/syntax a little bit to hopefully help with what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being able to replace `operator new()` and `operator delete()` (and their array versions) at program level may be sufficient for small program. If you have programs consisting of many millions lines of code, running many different threads this isn't at all suitable. You often want or even need better control. To make the use of custom allocators effective, you also need to be able to allocate subobjects using the same objects as the outer allocator.

For example, consider the use of memory arena to be used when answering a request in some sort of a server which is probably running multiple threads. Getting memory from `operator new()` is probably fairly expensive because it involves allocating a lock and finding a suitable chunk of memory in a heap which is getting more and more fragmented. To avoid this, you just want to allocate a few chunks of memory (ideally just one but you may not know the needed size in advance) and put all objects there. An allocator can do this. To do so, you need to inform all entities allocating memory about this chunk of memory, i.e. you need to pass the allocator to everything possibly allocating memory. If you allocate e.g. a `std::vector<std::string, A>` the `std::string` objects should know about the allocator: just telling the `std::vector<std::string, A>` where and how to allocate memory isn't enough to avoid most memory allocations: you also need to tell it to the `std::string` (well, actually the `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, B>` for a suitable allocator type `B` which is related to `A`).

That is, if you really mean to take control of your memory allocations, you definitely want to pass allocators to everything which allocates memory. Using replaced versions of the global memory management facilities may help you but it is fairly constrained. If you just want to write a custom container and memory allocation isn't much of your concern you don't necessarily need to bother. In big systems which are running for extensive periods of time memory allocation is one of the many concerns, however.

Comment: Your thread example doesn't make IMO much sense. In that case I'd just use instead a global allocator based on thread local storage for its data structures. Easier, simpler and safer in my opinion.

Comment: Have you used this approach on a code base consisting of a significant size with multiple groups contributing to the code? How did you areange for all programs to have exactly one replacement of thses operators? In the organisations I have worked for it never was the case that all programs used a common set up. ... even if the code didn't include a couple of millions lines of code. Having local control of the allocation mechanism is useful to me as I have no control over the entire program.

Answer (score 1):

Allocators are classes that define memory models to be used by Standard Library containers.

Every Standard Library container has its own default allocator, However the users of the container can provide their own allocators over the default.
This is for additional flexibility.
It ensures that users can provide their own allocator which provides an alternate form of memory management(eg: Memory Pools) apart from the regular heap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce a standard-compatible container then the answer is of course yes... allocators are described in the standard so they are required.

In my personal experience however allocators are not that useful... therefore if you are developing a container for a specific use to overcome some structural limitation of the standard containers then I'd suggest to forget about allocators unless you really see a reason for using them.

If instead you are developing a container just because you think you can do better than the standard vector then my guess is that you are wasting your time. I don't like the allocator idea design (dropping on the type something that shouldn't be there) but luckily enough they can be just ignored. The only annoyance with allocators when you don't need them (i.e. always) is probably some more confusion in error messages.. that however are a mess anyway.